# intent open chrome in a url - not in lollipop

Tags: google-chrome, android-intent

```
public void onClickApp(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This code open Google Chrome and open the web www.google.com.

On Android 5, only open Google Chrome but not load www.google.com.

why?

sorry for my bad english.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think thats beacuse the activity doesn't exist in android lollipop.
Try with this:

```
 public void onClickApp(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you... I found this solution:

 try {

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setComponent (ComponentName.unflattenFromString   ("com.android.chrome/ com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main"));
            i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
            i.setData(Uri.parse("chrome://history/"));
            startActivity(i);
}